# Django AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS doesn't see my validators

Tags: python, django

I needed password validators with Russian messages, so i rewrote existed validators.   **personalpage/accountpage/validators.py**:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.conf.urls import url, Path
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class MyUserAttributeSimilarityValidator:
...


class MyMinimumLengthValidator:
...

class MyCommonPasswordValidator:
...


class MyNumericPasswordValidator:
...
```

also, I indicated them in the settings.py
**personalpage/account/settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',    
'accountpage',
]
...
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'accountpage.validators.MyUserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'accountpage.validators.MyMinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'accountpage.validators.MyCommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'accountpage.validators.MyNumericPasswordValidator',
},
```

]

but when i register new user i get [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsJfH.png)

why django doesn't see my validators?

Comment: do you have `__init__.py` file in *accountpage* directory? is it an app?

Comment: sure 
my accountpage app:
accountpage
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── validators.py
│   └── views.py

Comment: Can you add this in the question please, its not readable in comments